# Updating database table by CSV file upload

Tags: javascript, sql-server, csv

I am working with CSV(Comma-separated values) to upload data in SQL Server,
I Inserted data by CSV but can't find any help to update table by csv file.
Anything  I'm missing?

Comment: As Dieter says, what have you tried?  Could you upload the CSV to a temporary table and then insert your main table using appropriate SQL?  It is hard to give you more details unless you tell us about your schema and show us your code.

Comment: I moved data from CSV file to SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord class ref ,and SQLServerBulkCopy's writeToServer() method to insert but I did not find any method to update by this api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV is just one of file formats, which is not related to sql directly.
Now you using tool which can only insert (it can be part of sql installation or not).
If you want to make other operations (update or other), you have to find another tool with functionality you need.